# Possible reasons (other than Open Firmware Password Protection) for not being able to boot into single user mode?

Tags: macos, startup, single-user

Recently I was attempting to install some new software for a user. I followed [these instructions](http://www.rit.edu/its/services/desktop_support/mac/xforcenewadminacccount.html) to create a new admin-level account but when I held down cmd+S while booting it still booted into the regular login GUI, rather than into Single User Mode. The user doesn't have Open Firmware Password Protection installed -- what other reasons could there be for cmd+S not working?

Comment: Try holding the "option" key while powering on, does it reach the Startup Manager (screen with the hard drives/systems listed)?  If so then try holding option AND command while powering on, does it skip this screen?  If not then the command key is faulty.

Comment: Please edit your question to include: the model identifier of the Mac, its boot ROM version and SMC version – you'll find those in System Information; the and the make and model of the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

### Core Storage

If FileVault 2 is enabled for the OS X startup volume, then EfiLoginUI will present a graphic login dialogue *before* the start of OS X – seconds after the startup chime.

If the startup key combination is timely, then startup should proceed to single user mode *after* a user's passphrase has been entered.

### Firmware

Whilst I don't know the model of your Mac, I can draw attention to a 2011 topic that was resolved in MacRumors forums:

- [Mac Mini won't recognize Apple Aluminum Keyboard startup keystrokes](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1197875)

### Wireless keyboards

[Apple Wireless Keyboards: Using startup keys](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3273)

If I recall correctly, one type of Apple wireless keyboard is (or was) known to be problematic … at the moment I can't find a reference – sorry.