# My Macbook Pro (2011) won't boot into single user mode

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, startup

I saw [Possible reasons (other than Open Firmware Password Protection) for not being able to boot into single user mode?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/139505/possible-reasons-other-than-open-firmware-password-protection-for-not-being-ab), but it didn't help any, since I'm using the laptop's keyboard.

Yes, my Mac can boot into other modes, like Recovery and Apple's Boot Manager, but it fails to boot into Single User.

Also, the command key works, so can anyone help with this?

Edit: I do not have FileVault enabled.

Answer (score 2):

You may considering using these steps to start up your Mac in single-user mode or verbose mode:

1. Shut down your Mac.
2. Press the power button to start up your Mac.
3. Immediately hold down the following keys:

   - Hold down Command-S for single-user mode.
   - Hold down Command-V for verbose mode.
4. You've successfully entered single-user mode or verbose mode when you see white text appear on the screen.

Hope it works.

Comment: That has been what I've tried, and it didn't work.

Comment: It booted right up into the normal login window.

Answer (score 0):

FileVault must be on. This is why you must enter your credentials after single-user mode is requested.

Comment: It is not, I checked it out in system preferences.